# Selecting just the middle section of an image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an image that has some CSS: `width:100%;`

Now the image is around `560px` high, but I wish to only select 300px of the image, cutting off the top and bottom of the image without squashing it.

Is it possible to do this?

I have looked at `crop` but you have to select the portions to do this, and so it won't work when trying to get just the middle.

[image: Example of image cropping desired]

Comment: Do you need the image to be cropped dinamically?

Comment: Yes with CSS. Not using `background-image`, the image has to be with `src=""`

Comment: If you don't care about IE, you can use  `img { object-fit: cover; }`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this.
This is using "clip-path" CSS value. 
This was mentioned in @Sam Jacob's post.

```
<style>
.clip-me {  
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(110px, 160px, 170px, 60px); 
  /* values describe a top/left point and bottom/right point */

  clip-path: inset(10px 20px 30px 40px); /* or "none" */
  /* values are from-top, from-right, from-bottom, from-left */

} 
</style>
<img class="clip-me" src="thing-to-be-clipped.png">
```

Note:  This CSS property does *not* work in IE.

Comment: Use clip-path carefully, it's not supported by IE: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: @Getz surprise, surprise. ;)

Comment: Many thanks, I'm not too bothered about IE anymore, no one should be using it, Microsoft should no longer continue it.

Comment: @user2924019 You might be right, and I agree with you, but IE is still one of the most used browsers...

Comment: Well around 20% or less in total. Which is why MS should stop leading people on and get rid of it.

Comment: @user2924019 Forget what I said. http://gs.statcounter.com/#all-browser-ww-monthly-201502-201502-bar shows that Chrome is the most used browser. Cheers. Use clip-path.

Comment: @pokekart2002 but you're still technically correct. It is one of the most used. 90% of our clients use IE, even when given the choice.

Answer (score 4):

Use Clip Path

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 100px, 100px, 0); /* clip: shape(top, right, bottom, left);*/
}
```

Edit: As mentioned in the comment, the position should be absolute or fixed for this to work

If you don't want to make the position absolute or fixed, set the image you want to display as a background in a container (td, div, span etc) and then adjust background-position to get the sprite you want.

> As the mozilla page [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip) says that using clip is not a web standard, considering using clip-path or background-position to achieve this.

```
img{  

  /* deprecated version */
  position: absolute; /* absolute or fixed positioning required */
  clip: rect(110px, 160px, 170px, 60px); /* or "auto" */
  /* values descript a top/left point and bottom/right point */

  /* current version (doesn't require positioning) */
  clip-path: inset(10px 20px 30px 40px); /* or "none" */
  /* values are from-top, from-right, from-bottom, from-left */

}
```

A detailed explanation [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/)

Comment: To have in mind: the clip property only works on elements with position: absolute or position: fixed. It won’t work with relative or static positioning.

Comment: @Jivings Then setting the background and adjusting the background-position is the best way to achieve this

Comment: @AravindBharathy `clip-path` is not deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Put a negative `margin-top` to your image, the parent will need an `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: I might be missing something but wouldn't a negative margin-top leave the bottom in place. So you would need something else to remove or hide the bottom section if you went this route.

Comment: You're right, you can simply add a margin-bottom negative to the image or fix the height of the container

Comment: this fails if you have a list of images and they vary in height

Answer (score 4):

You can use `clip-path`:

```
/* values are from-top, from-right, from-bottom, from-left */
.clip {
    clip-path: polygon(5% 5%, 80% 5%, 80% 60%, 90% 60%, 5% 60%);
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% 5%, 80% 5%, 80% 60%, 90% 60%, 5% 60%);
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/q08g3948/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could use `background-position` instead (which would be quite browser compatible).

I know you have stated 'no background image' - but this could be added dynamically through a script, as could the background-position if need be.

A quick sample would be:

```css
div{
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300);
  background-position:0 -100px;
  height:100px;
  width:300px;
  
  }
```

```html
<div></div>

<br/><br/>Original
<br/><br/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300"/>
```

Comment: Thanks I can see how it works. The reason why I asked to avoid using background image was so that this could be implemented into a Wordpress site without the need to modify files. It may be the only option though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a relative positioned div + absolute positioned image. Use `top: -999px; bottom: -999px; margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;` to vertically center the image. Absolutely responsive. No hardcoded pixel or percentage values.

```css
.image-wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* fixed height */
  height: 300px;
  /* for demonstration */
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5em red;
}
.image-wrap img {
  position: absolute;
  /* fit horizontally */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* center vertically */
  top: -1000px;
  bottom: -1000px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports/4" width="600" height="600">
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports/5" width="600" height="600">
</div>
```